# Robot Framework - Won't press button on stacked modals

Tags: xpath, automated-tests, robotframework

I am try to automate the button press on stacked Modal dialog (Modal 2 on my screenshot), but get the following error: Element locator `'/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/button[2]'` did not match any elements.
even though that is the path to the button.. what am I missing please.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the url?

Comment: I can't post the url for security reasons.

Comment: Add the html as you see it, then; this xpath looks automatically generated, and unstable - if the layout changes just a bit, it won't match the element. It will be much better if it was based off id, class, even text or other unique properties of the target element.

Comment: And to complement @TodorMinakov, the xpath is absolute. Maybe you can use relative xpath with more specific references to the second modal window?

Comment: Thanks. The reason for xpath is that there were hardly any IDs and lack of CSS to work with in the original application. I will try using your suggestions and work back.

Comment: Still stuck on this tried everything, used "Wait until element is visible" on the problem element still cannot locate. Must be because its a double modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugestion:
Check your DOM with attention (..)
Maybe you have some iframe in there?